# Laravel: SQLSTATE[23000] error with dataTables

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, datatable

Why do i get this error? I have the right relationships and in tinker, it works really well, do u guys have any idea about this?

Tinker:
[image]

Controller:

```
$emp = Empresa::find($request->empresa_id);
$mov = $emp->movimientos()->where('linea_id', intval($request->id_caso))->with('producto_nombre', 'costo_promedio');
return DataTables::of($mov)->make(true);
```

Error:
[image]

Table structure:
[image]

Thx for the help.

Comment: since there are multiple table in your query you must specify the table name in your condition `movimiento.linea_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ambiguous` error occurs when there are multiple columns with the same name and you dont specified its table

since there are multiple table and have a column with the same name in your query you must specify the table name in your condition

```
$emp = Empresa::find($request->empresa_id);
$mov = $emp->movimientos()->where('movimiento.linea_id', intval($request->id_caso))->with('producto_nombre', 'costo_promedio');
return DataTables::of($mov)->make(true);
```

Comment: It's working now, how a simple thing can make u waste so much time... thank you so much